# Split array of object by looping on keys and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Is there any way to sort this array of objects ? :

```
[ RowDataPacket { new_path: '1481640456051.natedogg.jpg' },
RowDataPacket { new_path: '1486655771055.natedogg.jpg' },
RowDataPacket { tag_id: 170 },
RowDataPacket { tag_id: 171 },
RowDataPacket { tag_id: 169 },
RowDataPacket { tag_id: 172 },
RowDataPacket { id: 1, tags: 'myfirstTag' },
RowDataPacket { id: 4, tags: 'wrong' },
RowDataPacket { id: 31, tags: 'premier' },
RowDataPacket { id: 169, tags: 'west' },
RowDataPacket { id: 170, tags: 'WOWW' },
RowDataPacket { id: 171, tags: 'liopppp' },
RowDataPacket { id: 172, tags: 'daftpunk' },
RowDataPacket { id: 173, tags: 'dfgdfg' },
RowDataPacket { id: 174, tags: 'sport' },
RowDataPacket { id: 175, tags: 'hhdhd' },
RowDataPacket { id: 176, tags: 'sdfsdfee' } ]
```

I want to have two arrays, the first one with everything until the last `tag_id` and a new array with inside `id` and the `tags`.

I don't know how to use .map properly.

Comment: This array is invalid.

Comment: what do you mean.. can you explain more.. what's your expectation ?

Comment: @challenger Every element should be stored inside separate object - `{ RowDataPacket :  { tag_id: 170 }}` or just delete these `RowDataPacket`'s.

Comment: what about one with `new_path` ?

Comment: maybe you should add nodejs tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array `filter` method but you have to correct your array syntax:

```js
var arr = [ { new_path: '1481640456051.natedogg.jpg' },
{ new_path: '1486655771055.natedogg.jpg' },
{ tag_id: 170 },
{ tag_id: 171 },
{ tag_id: 169 },
{ tag_id: 172 },
{ id: 1, tags: 'myfirstTag' },
{ id: 4, tags: 'wrong' },
{ id: 31, tags: 'premier' },
{ id: 169, tags: 'west' },
{ id: 170, tags: 'WOWW' },
{ id: 171, tags: 'liopppp' },
{ id: 172, tags: 'daftpunk' },
{ id: 173, tags: 'dfgdfg' },
{ id: 174, tags: 'sport' },
{ id: 175, tags: 'hhdhd' },
{ id: 176, tags: 'sdfsdfee' } ];

var arr1 = arr.filter(function(item) {
 return item.hasOwnProperty('tag_id');
});

var arr2 = arr.filter(function(item) {
 return item.hasOwnProperty('id') && item.hasOwnProperty('tags');
});

console.log(arr1, arr2)
```

If you're using ES2015 you can also use arrow functions to simplify above code:

```
var arr1 = arr.filter((item) => item.hasOwnProperty('tag_id'));
var arr2 = arr.filter((item) => item.hasOwnProperty('id') && item.hasOwnProperty('tags'));
```

Comment: Shouldn't be it `&&`?